# Get today,yesterday,last week,last month value in a row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I created a table for practise. I am new to SQL and using Postgresql to solve the question.

```
date            attendance

"2018-01-01"    111
"2018-01-02"    113
"2018-01-03"    100
"2018-01-04"    95
"2018-01-05"    105
"2018-01-08"    114
"2018-01-09"    114
"2018-01-10"    104
"2018-01-11"    95
"2018-01-12"    103
"2018-01-15"    93
"2018-01-16"    110
"2018-01-17"    99
"2018-01-18"    98
"2018-01-19"    107
"2018-01-22"    98
"2018-01-23"    112
"2018-01-24"    99
"2018-01-25"    91
"2018-01-26"    119
```

I want attendance of current day,the day before,the week before,the month before in the same row like:
[Image of result same as below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mfpsb.jpg)

```
"date_class","todayattendance","yesterdayattendance","weekattendance","monthattendance"
"2018-01-01","111",NULL,NULL,NULL
"2018-01-02","113","111",NULL,NULL
"2018-01-03","100","113",NULL,NULL
"2018-01-04","95","100",NULL,NULL
"2018-01-05","105","95",NULL,NULL
"2018-01-08","114",NULL,"111",NULL
"2018-01-09","114","114","113",NULL
"2018-01-10","104","114","100",NULL
"2018-01-11","95","104","95",NULL
"2018-01-12","103","95","105",NULL
"2018-01-15","93",NULL,"114",NULL
"2018-01-16","110","93","114",NULL
"2018-01-17","99","110","104",NULL
"2018-01-18","98","99","95",NULL
"2018-01-19","107","98","103",NULL
"2018-01-22","98",NULL,"93",NULL
"2018-01-23","112","98","110",NULL
"2018-01-24","99","112","99",NULL
"2018-01-25","91","99","98",NULL
"2018-01-26","119","91","107",NULL
"2018-01-29","92",NULL,"98",NULL
"2018-01-30","92","92","112",NULL
"2018-01-31","114","92","99",NULL
"2018-02-01","97","114","91","111"
"2018-02-02","93","97","119","113"
"2018-02-05","99",NULL,"92","105"
"2018-02-06","114","99","92",NULL
"2018-02-07","119","114","114",NULL
"2018-02-08","113","119","97","114"
"2018-02-09","109","113","93","114"
```

I used 3 joins for this

```
select  t.date_class
,max(t.attendance) as todayAttendance
,max(y.attendance) as yesterdayAttendance
,max(w.attendance) as weekAttendance
,max(m.attendance) as monthAttendance

from (select *
      from attendance t
     ) t left join
     (select ((date_class+INTERVAL '1 day')::date) date_class,attendance
      from attendance y
     )y
     on t.date_class = y.date_class
     left join
     (select ((date_class+INTERVAL '1 week')::date) date_class,attendance
      from attendance w
     )w
     on t.date_class = w.date_class
     left join
     (select ((date_class+INTERVAL '1 month')::date) date_class,attendance
      from attendance m
     )m
     on t.date_class = m.date_class
group by t.date_class
order by t.date_class
limit 30
```

How can I reduce joins or this is the most optimized solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use window functions:

```
select a.*,
       max(attendance) over (order by date_class
                             range between '1 day' preceding and '1 day' preceding
                            ) as prev_day,
       max(attendance) over (order by date_class
                             range between '7 day' preceding and '7 day' preceding
                            ) as prev_week,
       max(attendance) over (order by date_class
                             range between '1 month' preceding and '1 month' preceding
                            ) as prev_month
from attendance a;
```

The `month` may not work as you expect, because months have different numbers of days.  But this is what you are asking for.